# How to combine two separate mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

What is the correct syntax for combining these mysql queries?

```
$reserved = mysql_query("Select * from reservations where $timestamp >= ReservationStart AND $timestamp <= ReservationEnd");
```

and

```
$reserved2 = mysql_query("Select * from reservations where $ReservationEnd >= ReservationStart AND $ReservationEnd <= ReservationEnd");
```

I would like the reservation to meet both of these criteria but I am quite new to using mysql (and I know it's deprecated, but for the purpose of what i'm using it is easier), so i'm not sure how to put these two together.

Comment: How do you want them combined? Do you want the reservations that meet both criteria (combine the two conditions with `AND`) or that meet either criteria (combine them with `OR`)?

Comment: I would like the reservation to meet both criteria

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I recognise this and this is probably the last instance of me using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why the query wasn't working.

It was simply because the syntax for the query was wrong, as I needed the inverted commas around the variables for it to work properly, like this:

```
$reserved = mysql_query("Select * from reservations where '$timestamp' BETWEEN ReservationStart AND ReservationEnd AND '$ReservationEnd' BETWEEN ReservationStart AND ReservationEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the `WHERE` clauses with `AND`. You can also use the `BETWEEN` operator instead of testing both `>=` and `<=`.

```
$reserved = mysql_query("Select * 
    from reservations 
    where $timestamp BETWEEN ReservationStart AND ReservationEnd
    AND $ReservationEnd BETWEEN ReservationStart AND ReservationEnd") or die(mysql_error());
```